# How to encapsulate INDIRECT into INDEX using R/C notation in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a range using INDIREKT, I added COL() to see how big this range is:

```
=COL(INDIRECT("R1C1:R1C5"; 0))
```

As you can see, I'm using the R/C notation for row/colum adressing. The result is simply all numbers from 1 to 5 in the first row:

[image]

Now I'm just using the numbers to address letters from a string, like this:

```
="_" & MID("HELLO"; COL(INDIRECT("Z1S1:Z1S5"; 0)); 1)
```

This works as expected and returns:

[image]

Now there's a random cell somewhere on the sheet, I named this cell "_H". The cell just contains the letter H:

[image]

I did this for E, L and O, too.

Now I add a third row containing this.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A2);1;1)
```

Pulling this to the width of 5 columns the result is as expected:

[image]

And here comes my problem: How to use the R/C notation? This comes into my mind:

```
=INDIRECT("Z2S1"; 0)
```

This returns the correct value of row 2, column 1 aka A2. Which is _H. Now I put this into the INDEX formula, expecting that Excel takes the _H, use this as the address for INDEX and returns the value from 1;1 of this "name range":

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("R2C1";0);1;1)
```

But the result is simply:

[image]

When I remove the quotes, Excel is complaining, so this is not working:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(R2C1;0);1;1)
```

(Apparently, because the Excel setting says I prefer A1-notation).

But I wonder why it's not working, when I tell excel explicitly to use the R/C notation?

Well, it seems like Excel just takes the range and the value from R1C1 in this range - which is _R. So I was trying around to make this column-argument "dynamic". I know that this returns the column index for the whole range.

```
 =COL(INDIRECT("R1C1:R1C5";0))
```

This returns 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 for the particular columns.
So why not putting it into the formula above:

```
 =INDEX(INDIRECT("Z2S" & COL(INDIRECT("R1C1:R1C5";0));0);1;COL(INDIRECT("R1C1:R1C5";0)))
```

This returns #VALUE as an error.

How to indirectly address a cell or even a range to get a value from a particular coordinate (using INDEX)? I specifically need the R/C notation because I need to address ranges numerically (for example column 1 instead of column A and so on).

Comment: "But I wonder why it's not working, when I tell excel explicitly to use the R/C notation?": I think because `INDIRECT` assumes a string that gets evaluated - R2C1 is neither a string nor a cell reference. Although I don't understand for what you need this: do you know `SEQUENCE`- it's availabe in Excel 365 - I think this will do what you want - without the indirect-stuff - or even better `MAKEARRAY`

Comment: @Ike Maybe I do not understand you, R2C1 is indeed a valid cell reference. INDIRECT("R2C1"; 0) or even INDIRECT("R(-1)C1"; 0) work like a charm. I tried SEQUENCE, but its not working in "encapsulation":  Excel does not allow this =COL(SEQUENCE(1;5)). MAKEARRAY does not work on my version, I don't know why. But I guess I found the missing link, will phrase it into an answer.

Comment: But `R2C1` without quotation marks is not the same when used with `INDIRECT`. -- You don't need `COL` - just `SEQUENCE`- it will return the array you need. What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: @Ike I want to have one formular, put to A1, that expands to n cols, where every column refers to a different named range, to get information from that range. Like this: =INDEX(INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Z2S1";0);0);1;1) - which returns the expected value from _H at R1/C1 - but now for all 5 columns from the example above.

Comment: Your first example could be achieved like this: `="_" & MID("HELLO", SEQUENCE(1,5),1)`

Comment: @Ike Yes, but how do I use the values (_H, _E, ...) as a reference to the name range to get the value from R1/C1? (In a second row, apparently, but I thought I could combine it in one colume - the goal is a LAMBDA function) (Thanks for your assistance, btw!)

Comment: HEUREKA! Got it, it's MAP! So easy! Thanky you pushing me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can condense your solution - no `INDEX(X;1;1) needed:

```vb
=LET(word,"HELLO",
     singleCharacters,"_" & MID(word,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(word)),1),
     MAP(singleCharacters,LAMBDA(a,INDIRECT(a))))
```

Using `LET` makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: That's neat, too, but the final solution has named ranges over several rows and columns, that's why I need INDEX. I ignored this fact, to not overcomplicate it. That's why I was explicitly asking for INDEX & INDIRECT. Thanks anyways, LET indeed is a precious side note.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's easier than I thought, Excel has this wonderful MAP formula:

```
=MAP(A2:E2; LAMBDA(a; INDEX(INDIRECT(a); 1; 1)))
```

Now every particular column points to the reference/range name and INDEX can use this, to get the value from R1/C1 of the particular named range.

This can even be more improved into a one-liner:

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(1;LEN("HELLO")); LAMBDA(i; INDEX(INDIRECT("_" & MID("HELLO"; i; 1));1;1)))
```

I can put this everywhere I want, I just need to define the named ranges.

Appreciation to @Ike who lead into the right direction.